# Organizing packages that provide functionality to each other and to the main program

Tags: python

I have the following structure on a Python program:

```
my_program/
    main.py
    packages/
        __init.py__
        package_to_share/
           __init__.py
            main_to_share.py
            module_to_share.py
        package_A/
           __init__.py
            main_A.py
            some_module_A.py
        package_B/
           __init__.py
            main_B.py
            some_module_B.py
```

The package `package_to_share` provides functionality that every package in the `packages` folder uses and that `main.py` at the root folder uses.

I also want to be able to `cd` into each package and be able to run `main_X.py`.

So far I figured out how to access functionality **from `main.py`**:

```
import packages.package_A.some_module_A
import packages.package_to_share.module_to_share
```

but I am having problems accessing the functionality in `package_to_share` from regular packages (e.g. `package_A`)

For example, when in `main_A.py` or `some_module_A.py`, typing `import packages.package_to_share.module_to_share` fails.

This leads me to following questions questions:

1. Given the specifics of my problem, with packages to be shared (accessed) by files at the root folder and by other packages, is there a better way to organize my folders ? Does this organization of modules and files in general conform to good standards in Python?
2. The following looks incredibly hacky to me, but it's the best thing I came up with to make sure my regular modules see the `"shared"` modules:

   ```
   p_this_file   = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
   new_sys_path.append(os.path.join(p_cwd, '..')
   new_sys_path.extend(sys.path)
   sys.path      = new_sys_path
   ```

   It also does not prevent my regular packages from importing each other.

Comment: I've had **exactly** this same confusion for some time now. I can't find a guide to "idiomatic python codebase design done right" anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manipulating the path for imports (which I don't recommend), you could use relative imports within `module_A`:

```
from .. import shared
```

That is what I sometimes do, though I generally have my packages installed so I can reference them fully where I need to use them:

```
from my_module import shared
```

Comment: When you're developing a codebase that contains multiple components which internally depend on each other, it's not "installed" yet.

Comment: That's very true and so relative imports are a way to support that. Personally, I sometimes find it worth the pain of installing locally frequently for development if it is a non-issue in production.

Comment: That might be another option for your answer. If running a top-level `setup.py` that installs the whole codebase each time you want to run something is the way to go, I'm thinking that might be the most attractive option (for me personally anyway).